# Python Django Class Syntax Errror

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am relatively new to python and django. Trying to implement a python class but get this strange syntax error

```
from invoice.models import Invoice
from invoice.serializers import InvoiceSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class InvoiceList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            invoices = Invoice.objects.all()
            serializer = InvoiceSerializer(invoices, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except Invoice.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        serializer = InvoiceSerializer(invoices, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = InvoiceSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST


class InvoiceDetail(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Invoice.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Invoice.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        invoice=self.get_object(pk)
        serializer=InvoiceSerializer(invoice)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        invoice=self.get_object(pk)
        serializer=InvoiceSerializer(invoice, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        invoice=self.get_object(pk)
        invoice.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

this is error I get. I don't understand why it's giving me this error because error seems right to me

class InvoiceDetail(APIView):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: One `)` is missing just before `InvoiceDetail` class. ie, `return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST`

Comment: Hint: syntax errors points to the place where the issue is detected, which can be a few (and sometimes quite a few) lines after the place where the real issue is.

Answer (score 1):

In class `InvoiceList` change

`return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST`

to

`return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`